# won't boot anymore: how to disable /etc/fstab check?

Tags: 15.10

With the recent update to 15.10 our machines are not booting at all anymore when some optional discs specified in /etc/fstab are not plugged anymore.

As consequence you must boot into recovery mode and comment that discs out in the /etc/fstab file. This also requires expertise and is a complete nogo.

How do we get the good old and standard behaviour (as in ANY other linux dist) back ?

This behaviour is really damaging hardware because if you don't know what to do when your computer is stuck at booting, the only choice left is/was :

1. CTRL+ALT + F2 which also doesn't work anymore in that case (congrats!)
2. Hold the power button to turn off and risk substantial damages of your discs because that can cause head crashes on some discs (congrats!)

btw: the very same behaviour broke also the update process from 14 to 15. It took 4 hours of more advanced expertise to figure out why the update is stuck and won't boot into anything.

If it helps, this is one of the fstab entries:

/dev/sde1 /mnt/anneDisc               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       0

**Update**

there were 2 answers but have been deleted:

1. sudo systemctl disable systemd-fsck-root && sudo systemctl disable systemd-fsck@ // but boot was still stuck
2. Then somebody wrote I should change my fstab entries to /dev/sde1 /mnt/anneDisc               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0 0 but this also didn't change anything.

**Update -2** 
thanks to the accepted answer, changing to /dev/sde1 /mnt/anneDisc ext4 auto,nofail 0 0 kept my world running

Comment: `Ctrl alt F2`, not `Ctrl alt 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to automount the optional disk at boot time or not.

If you want to automount the optional disk without halting the system when not present, then change the line to:

`/dev/sde1 /mnt/anneDisc ext4 auto,nofail 0 0`

Else, you can specify the disk as noauto

`/dev/sde1 /mnt/anneDisc ext4 noauto 0 0`

Comment: thanks, I will try that and comment here. I am still curious why this is only a problem in Ubuntu.  In debian no problem, no matter what you've got in your fstab.

Comment: thanks again! /dev/sde1 /mnt/anneDisc ext4 auto,nofail 0 0 did do it!